# Does anyone else have this showing in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

This hasn't happened before, but recently I noticed eclipse having two windows opened at the same time. Is this normal? Or a virus of some sort? Here is a picture to show you what I mean:

http://icap.me/i/SdHY5YGBB6.php

Sorry for the bad quality (took it on my phone). Eclipse is on the left and the window opened with it is on the right. Thanks

Comment: You could move the camera away from the screen for a better quality image.BTW,what does the second screen say?

Comment: The other window doesn't show anything, btw, forgot to mention I am using Windows 8, Java 7 if that matters at all.

Comment: It's really hard to say what the problem is if it doesn't show anything,plus the quality of the picture.Can you take a better picture and update your question? Or have you tried another version of Eclipse on the same machine with the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a second window before when Eclipse has been terminated just after opening its splash screen, leaving the screen open from a process in some odd state.  Use task manager to see if you can force one of the processes closed.

Comment: There is no other process running, would it be one of the java.exe processes maybe? Because there is no other eclipse.exe process. I also forgot to mention that this does not happen all the time, but happens randomly. Virus maybe?